# Compatible tyre widths for 622 × 17 rims?

Tags: tire, rims, compatibility, hybrid-bike, tyre-width

I have 622 × 17 rims on my hybrid and currently have 700×40c tyres on (came with the bike).

I need a new rear tyre but I am not sure what I can get. From what I can find I should be fitting fairly narrow tyres in the 25-28C range?

[image: Rim]

[image: current tyre]

Comment: https://www.sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html#width

Comment: I read that (least confusing) and others (mixed bag!) and appears a 17mm rim (internal) can take from 1.4 to 2.2 x the width. But that’s 24 - 38...and I already have a 40C on there!?

Comment: Yeah, I think Sheldon's table understates the max size in some cases.  About the best I've seen, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have a specific reason to change size, get the same.

This kind of combination is common, but over the last years there has been some fuss about too narrow rims, in some part because people with limited riding experience like to repeat what they have heard and in part because manufacturers are pushing wider rims.

Comment: Thanks - I'd like to go down to 35C/30C's as I use this bike for training rather than commuting and I *think !* I'll be able to get better rolling tyres at this width without losing too much comfort or grip.

Comment: Then why not, but rolling resistance does not depend that much on width. Read tests instead and pick a tire that gets good results.

Answer (score 0):

Do a google search for 'bicycle tire rim width' and you'll find many charts that give the ranges of tire width ranges for rim widths. A 40mm tire is well within the range of a 17mm rim.

You can go to a 32mm tire, and you might get slightly better rolling resistance, but probably not as much as you are hoping for.